# C# DTO get Id of Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto

When I want to create an entity using a DTO I want to get the Id of the recently inserted entity in the DTO that lives in my controller.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(HotelsViewModel hotelsViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        HotelsDTO hotelDTO = _mapper.Map<HotelsDTO>(hotelsViewModel);

        _hotelService.Create(hotelDTO);
        _hotelService.AddHotelAmenities(hotelDTO.Id, hotelsViewModel.SelectedAmenities);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(hotelsViewModel);
}
```

Service:

To retrieve the Id back in my controller should I change the return type of the Create method as an integer or is there another way to make this work?

```
public void Create(TDTO entity)
{
    T t = _mapper.Map<T>(entity);
    _repository.Create(t);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

After the savechanges gets hit the id of t is getting set but I'm failing to retrieve the id in my DTO object back in the controller.

Any advice?

Comment: Try searching, this has been discussed plenty of times. You lose the relation between viewmodel and DTO through the mapping, so an update to one does not update the other. Either return the ID, return the DTO, use `out` parameters to do the same or generate the ID on beforehand and pass it to `Create()`. The latter would conform to Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS), which can be viewed as contra-pragmatic.

Comment: After `SaveChanges` is called, your `t.ID` should has its value. So, if you set `entity.ID = t.ID;` after `_unitOfWork.Commit();` it should work for you.

Comment: @Adil no, the entity is mapped from the DTO, which is mapped from the viewmodel. The update to the DTO won't update the viewmodel.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I see what you mean, but I do not think that OP needs viewModel.ID, I think he/she needs DTO.ID as it is used like `_hotelService.AddHotelAmenities(hotelDTO.Id, hotelsViewModel.SelectedAmenities);`.

Comment: @Adil you're right about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `entity.Id = t.Id;` right after committing changes, i.e. right after the line: `_unitOfWork.Commit();`